# Ubuntu Permission Change Error

Tags: permissions, mount, chmod, read-only, copy

I Recently Installed Ubuntu Mate
And Used Ubuntu As Desktop Environment
I've Faced A Problem OF Copying/Creating A new Dir
I've used The Both Of

1. sudo mount -o remount, rw
2. chmod
   to Change The rw Permissions

i've solved the problem in certain drive/directories
but i didn't work for some others

[image]

[image]

So Please , Can I Get Any Help??

Answer (score 1):

Linux works with a system of ownership and permissions. You can only read and write as normal users to locations that you own or where you have permissions, i.e. under your home folder or on file systems of removable drives that *do not* support unix permissions. For removable drives formatted with a linux file system (supporting unix file permission), you first need to grant permission for the entire partition, or for selected folders on the partition, before a user has write access.

Prefer to change user permissions using the command line. There is currently no good way to graphically change user permissions - the only way is to run the file manager with root permissions, but this can damage your configuration.

To change ownership, use `chown`, to change permissions, use `chmod`.

- An easy way to identify the folder where you want to change ownership, is to navigate to it with the file manager. When in the folder, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This displays the file path to the folder. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to the clipboard.
- Now, you easily can change the owner of that folder to yourself: `sudo chown $USER:$USER "<path_to_folder>"`. Where it says `<path_to_folder>`, paste the path you copied in the previous step. Make sure to keep the parenthesis (`"..."`) around the path, especially in case the path name contains spaces.
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and supply your user password (`sudo` causes you to assume administrator priviledges).